# Ionic v1 auto turn on push notifications capabilities

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I have an script that uploads the apps directly to the AppStore. The problem is that the Push Notifications capability is not being turned on automatically.

I am using:
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.1
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
Node       : v6.11.0
npm        : 3.10.10
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

And phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 plugin.

Any idea on how I can turn this automatically on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you post your script's code?, it might help, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Fastlane for the delivery, you can use this in your Fastfile:

```
sh "fastlane produce enable_services --push-notification"
```

Otherwise

I used this Ruby script in a project. Maybe it helps for you. 
Remember to rename the "name" variable
https://gist.github.com/aitoraznar/87e2c3b458b2d799ae049be5e84d578d

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'xcodeproj'

name = "app_name" // <-Replace with your app name
projectpath = "platforms/ios/" + name + ".xcodeproj"
puts "Adding entitlement push to " + name
puts "Opening " + projectpath
proj = Xcodeproj::Project.open(projectpath)
entitlement_path = name + "/" + name + ".entitlements"

group_name= proj.root_object.main_group.name

file = proj.new_file(entitlement_path)

attributes = {}
proj.targets.each do |target|
    attributes[target.uuid] = {"SystemCapabilities" => {"com.apple.Push" => {"enabled" => 1}}}
    #target.add_file_references([file])
    puts "Added to target: " + target.uuid
end
proj.root_object.attributes['TargetAttributes'] = attributes

proj.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.store("CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS", entitlement_path)
end
puts "Added entitlements file path: " + entitlement_path

#proj.recreate_user_schemes
proj.save
```